# Получить только число из переменной, содержащей текст + число + текст

Tags: javascript

Пишу javascript, и есть переменная, в которой хранится нужное мне число. Я бы его вытащил через `parseFloat`, но проблема в том что оно хранится в таком виде (50%). Т.е перед числом идет символ `(` из-за этого `parseFloat` возвращает `NaN`. Как мне вытащить в таком случае число?

Comment: Вам надо воспользоваться "регулярными выражениями". Причем в Вашем случае - самый простой вариант, базовый: вытащить цифры из текста. Идеален для самообучения. Почитайте в сети об этом. Например: http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если строка всегда будет во формате `({число}%)`, то можно просто удалить первый символ и последные два символа, вот так:

```
var str = "(50.5%)";
var x = parseFloat(str.slice(1, -2));
```

Answer (score 2):

[ссылка от](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+) [cyadvert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186791/cyadvert) [на функшен](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+)

[Сама регекспа](https://regex101.com/r/tA8cS2/2) `/([0-9]+)(?:[\%])/`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Подправил комментарий